# Unable to add a particular repository(14.04)

Tags: apt, repository

I was trying to install two packages that needs a particular repository. But getting error.

Need help to fix that.

Packages: **bamtools** and **libbamtools-dev**

Repository :

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main universe
```

I have edited `/etc/apt/sources` file and added the above repository then ran `apt-get update`

while running the apt-get update command , I am getting the bellow error :

```
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: That looks like you screwed up your sources file. Can you post a dump of it or at least of the lines belonging to those repost?

Comment: 'apt-get update' is running properly without my added repository name. The above repository name causing the problem.